# Chrome for Android data storage grows when using the HTML Media Capture API

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, camera, image-capture

We have a mobile HTML5 application where one important aspect of it is that users can take photos that ultimately end up being sent to a web server. To capture the images in Chrome for Android, we use the HTML Media Capture API:

```
<input id="capture" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

The problem that we are having is that, over time, the data storage usage for Chrome (under Settings / Apps / Chrome) increases to the point of a few gigabytes, which ends up consuming all of the available storage on the users' devices. This data does not appear to be listed anywhere under Chrome's site settings and the only way we have found so far to release the data is to clear Chrome's application data which is not desirable solution.

I suspect what is happening is that when Chrome interfaces with the Camera app to capture a photo, the photo data is saved into Chrome's data (which we read using a FileReader object), but the photo data is not being released and accumulates over time.

Here is the code for a simple HTML5 page that illustrates this issue. After capturing 10 or so images you can go into Settings / Apps / Chrome and see that the data storage has increased by a few megabytes and the only way to clear the data is to clear all of the data for Chrome.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Camera Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  Capture Image: <input id="capture" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know if:

- What I suspect about the photo data accumulating is correct?
- Is there a way to tell Chrome to release the photo data after the application is finished with it?

Comment: This seems like a bug in Chrome and it’s at least worth taking time to report it at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list so the resolution can be tracked. (And posting a link to the bug report back here if/when you raise one.)

Comment: Thanks. I posted a bug. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=574442

Comment: Excellent—I’ll give some chrome developer friends a heads-up about that bug

Comment: The bug that I posted against Chrome (issue 574442) has been marked as fixed. See [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=574442) for details.

Comment: Yeah that 1-hour thing should be documented somewhere clearly or maybe even yet there should be some heads-up message that gets logged to the devtools console about it. Maybe that’s not practical but I don’t know how else as a developer you’d ever be able to discover that was the behavior.